# Can't install Ubuntu 14.04.01 on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, live-usb, bootloader

I used Universal USB Installer to create a live boot on a USB drive, but when I try to boot from the drive, I don't get the installation menu, just a black screen to enter commands on. I disabled secure boot, and quick launch as well.

Comment: Try these methods. This explains well.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a surface pro, I suggest you restore the original windows 8.1 and then try again.

I managed to get ubuntu running on a surface pro 2, but it involved a lot of kerfuffle. As part of that, I found it was totally possible to get the surface into a state where it would not boot anything except the restore USB from the original windows installation.

The solution to this was to restore the tablet and then try the Ubuntu install again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case you just set the legacy (bios boot) mode and turn off the secure boot and then open win 8.1 and then start the installation of Ubuntu using executable file that in the U.S.B. drive